# Audio recording is not uploading in server folder

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, audio-recording, uploading

The Recording of audio is done by `recorder.js` But uploading to folder uploads is not working.

The code is here:

```
var upload = document.createElement('a');
    upload.href="#";
    upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
    upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
          var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload=function(e) {
              if(this.readyState === 4) {
                  console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
              }
          };
          var fd=new FormData();
          fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
          xhr.open("POST","upload1.php",true);
          xhr.send(fd);
    })
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))//add a space in between
    li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li

    //add the li element to the ol
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
```

Code for upload1.php is

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES); 

$size = $_FILES['audio_data']['size']; 
$input = $_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name']; 
$output = $_FILES['audio_data']['name'];
$out=$output.".wav"; 

$dest='uploads/'.$out;
move_uploaded_file($input,$dest);
?>
```

Comment: might be useful to add your error messages on client/server side

Comment: _"is not working"_ is a terrible error description that doesn't really help us narrow down the issue. Please let us know what debugging you've done. Any errors in the browsers console? Have you checked the web servers error log? Have you checked the network tab in the browsers dev tools to see if an ajax request is made at all, or what it sends/returns?

Comment: @Kavya You should set the listener on `upload.onreadystatechange` instead of `upload.onload`